# why webpack does not like this expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I tried to build my reactjs app using webpack and babel.

I started this app from react starter which comes with `react-scripts build` which worked before. However, it's a black box and didn't really provide all the features I need, especially when it comes to that a module doesn't like UglifyJS.

My `webpack.config.js` looks like this which is pretty simple:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build_webpack');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

module.exports = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/index.js',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/, 
        loader: 'babel'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and I have this config in my `package.js`:

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "reactbuild": "react-scripts build",
        "webpackbuild": "webpack --watch",
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      }
```

Also my `.babelrc` file only has this:

```
{
  "presets" : ["es2015", "es2016", "react"]
}
```

However, the code that worked in `react-scripts build` failed here, and the error output says:

ERROR in ./src/Pages/SearchTool/SearchResult.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (100:13)

(the error is referring to the data input argument)

```
renderChip = (data) => {
         return (
           <Chip
             key={data.key}
```

I don't really see what is so special about this expression. I don't think this is very commonly used but should be legal though. Also, one reason that I switched to webpack was that the previous react build doesn't like es6, but one of my module which is important is written in es6.

I wonder what was missing in my config or other places. Thanks for all the help!

**Edit:**

my package.js:

```
{
  "name": "myCoolApps",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "react-scripts": "0.7.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ace": "git+https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace.git#master",
    "antd": "^2.7.2",
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.4.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "card": "^2.2.1",
    "card-react": "^1.2.6",
    "chat-template": "0.0.22",
    "codemirror": "^5.25.0",
    "credit-card-type": "^5.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "d3": "^4.7.4",
    "firechat": "^3.0.1",
    "firepad": "^1.4.0",
    "flux": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "history": "^1.17.0",
    "little-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "material-ui": "^0.16.6",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    "quill": "^1.2.3",
    "rc-calendar": "^7.6.5",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-autosuggest": "^7.0.1",
    "react-cookie": "^1.0.4",
    "react-credit-card": "^0.20.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dropzone": "^3.8.0",
    "react-event-timeline": "^1.2.2",
    "react-infinite": "^0.10.0",
    "react-infinite-scroller": "^1.0.7",
    "react-list": "^0.8.3",
    "react-notification-system": "^0.2.12",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "seedrandom": "^2.4.2",
    "simplewebrtc": "^2.2.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "superagent": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^1.15.0",
    "y-array": "^10.0.6",
    "y-indexeddb": "^8.1.9",
    "y-leveldb": "0.0.1",
    "y-map": "^10.0.5",
    "y-memory": "^8.0.8",
    "y-richtext": "^9.0.8",
    "y-text": "^9.3.2",
    "y-webrtc": "^8.0.7",
    "y-websockets-client": "^8.0.15",
    "yjs": "^12.1.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "reactbuild": "react-scripts build",
    "webpackbuild": "webpack",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried the env preset, and now my `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```
{
  "presets":
  [
    "react",
    [
      "env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "uglify": false,
          "node": "current",
          "debug": true,
        },
      }
    ],
  ],
}
```

However, it still complains about this expression:

```
ERROR in ./src/Pages/SearchTool/SearchResult.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (100:13)

   98 |   }
   99 | 
> 100 |   renderChip = (data) => {
      |              ^
  101 |     return (
  102 |       <Chip
  103 |         key={data.key}

 @ ./src/Pages/Connections/Connections.js 43:20-57
```

The function originally looks like this in the program (Note: it is inside a class):

```
  renderChip = (data) => {
    return (
      <Chip
        key={data.key}
        onRequestDelete={this.handleRequestDelete}
        style={{
          borderRadius: '6px',
          margin: '0 4px',
          height: 35
        }}
      >
        {data.label}
      </Chip>
    );
  }
```

And also I tried include plugins manually

The place this function in my class looks like:

```
class Name extends Component {
    constructor(props) {...}

    renderChip = (data) => {
        return (
          <Chip
            key={data.key}
            onRequestDelete={this.handleRequestDelete}
            style={{
              borderRadius: '6px',
              margin: '0 4px',
              height: 35
            }}
          >
            {data.label}
          </Chip>
        );
      }

    render() {...}
}
```

I manually included `transform-es2015-function-name` and `transform-es2015-arrow-functions`, but they didn't work. Are there some other plugins I need to include manually? Or is it caused by some other reason?

**Solved**

The solution is changing the function experssion to:

```
renderChip() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: What is your webpack version?

Comment: it is version 4.4.4

Comment: I asked for `webpack` version, latest is 2.4.1. So what is yours?

Comment: oh my bad. according to my package.js it seems to be 1.15.0. and the one react-script is using seems to be 1.13.3.

Comment: Did you declare your `renderChip` directly in class?

Comment: Yes, I will add it into update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add [babel-preset-env](https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env) package.

Your `.babelrc` should look something like this: (`["env" ...]` part is important here)

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "uglify": true,
        "node": "current"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Reading the docs I mentioned above. UglifyJS does not support ES6. It is recommended to use [babel-minify](https://github.com/babel/babili) instead.

> UglifyJS does not currently support any ES6 syntax, so if you are
>   using Uglify to minify your code, targeting later browsers may cause
>   Uglify to throw syntax errors.
>
> To prevent these errors - specify the uglify option, which will enable
>   all plugins and, as a result, fully compile your code to ES5. However,
>   the useBuiltIns option will still work as before, and only include the
>   polyfills that your target(s) need.

**UPDATE:**

Try installing/reinstalling these packages. you may not need all of them, but you may find use in them later on.

```
npm install --save-dev babel-core babel-loader babel-polyfill babel-preset-env babel-register babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread babel-plugin-transform-regenerator
```

Write

```
renderChip(data) {
```

instead of

```
renderChip = (data) => {
```

Comment: First thanks for the advice! However, it didn't actually work in this case. It is still complaining about the function declaration expression. I tried several things which I put in the UPDATE in the original post.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please install these packages. Please correct your code.

Comment: There was small edit, please update your code to `renderChip(data) {` let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes, it worked once I took out all the similar expressions!

Comment: Very nice, Glad I could help you

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare class methods with assignment operator directly in class body, instead you can do following.

```
renderChip(data) {
    return (
      <Chip
        key={data.key}
        onRequestDelete={this.handleRequestDelete}
        style={{
          borderRadius: '6px',
          margin: '0 4px',
          height: 35
        }}
      >
        {data.label}
      </Chip>
    );
  }
```

You can read about ES6 classes [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/object-oriented-javascript-deep-dive-es6-classes/).

Hope this helped!

Comment: I think you are right. However, this did work in my development build and react-script build. Is it an es5 standard? If it is, is there a way to set up my build system so that I can handle a mixing of es5 and es6? I did most of my work following es6 standard, but this several functions came from my partner who is much older than me lol.

Comment: You can't use `class` in ES5, since basically it is ES6 feature. Of course you can use both ES5 and ES6 in your code, you just need to add babel presets to compile ES6 to browser compatible code. As I saw in your webpack you already have es2015 preset (which is same as ES6).

Comment: Read about ES standards here https://benmccormick.org/2015/09/14/es5-es6-es2016-es-next-whats-going-on-with-javascript-versioning/

Comment: Yea you are right, it worked once I took out all the similar expressions.